# How does one get the table-column name for a complex property of an entity? (VB 2010/EF4)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I've written the following code (VB 2010/EF 4) for getting storage (database) table/column names from (conceptual) entity/property names:

```
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.EntityClient
Imports System.Data.Metadata.Edm
Imports System.Data.Objects.DataClasses
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class ConvertConceptualToStore
    Private Shared Function GetTableName(Of T As EntityObject)() As String
    Dim type As Type = GetType(T) : Dim at = GetAttribute(Of EdmEntityTypeAttribute)(type)
    Return at.Name
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetColumnName(Of T As EntityObject) _
        (ByVal propertySelector As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Object))) As String

    If propertySelector Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("""" & propertySelector.ToString & """ is null.")
    End If

    Dim propertyInfo As PropertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(propertySelector.Body)
    Dim attribute As DataMemberAttribute = _
        GetAttribute(Of DataMemberAttribute)(propertyInfo)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Name) Then
        Return propertyInfo.Name
    Else
        Return attribute.Name
    End If
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetAttribute(Of T As Class) (ByVal memberInfo As MemberInfo) As T
    If memberInfo Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("""" & memberInfo.ToString & """ is null.")
    End If

    Dim customAttributes() As Object = _
        memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(T), False)
    Dim attribute As T = _
        DirectCast(customAttributes.Where(Function(a) TypeOf a Is T).First(), T)
    Return attribute
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetPropertyInfo(ByVal propertySelector As Expression) As PropertyInfo
    If propertySelector Is Nothing Then
        Throw New Exception("""" & propertySelector.ToString & """ is null.")
    End If

    Dim memberExpression As MemberExpression = _
        TryCast(propertySelector, MemberExpression)
    If memberExpression Is Nothing Then
        Dim unaryExpression As UnaryExpression = _
            TryCast(propertySelector, UnaryExpression)
        If unaryExpression IsNot Nothing _
                AndAlso unaryExpression.NodeType = ExpressionType.Convert Then
            memberExpression = TryCast(unaryExpression.Operand, MemberExpression)
        End If
    End If
    If memberExpression IsNot Nothing _
            AndAlso memberExpression.Member.MemberType = MemberTypes.Property Then
        Return DirectCast(memberExpression.Member, PropertyInfo)
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("No property reference was found.", "propertySelector")
    End If
    End Function

    ' Invocation example
    'Public Shared Function Test()
    'Dim table As String = GetTableName(Of User)()
    'Dim column As String = GetColumnName(Of User)(Function(u) u.Name)
    'End Function
End Class
```

QUESTIONS:

1. Am I correct in assuming that the code DOESN'T require an ObjectContext or
   Data.CSSpace?
2. **What if a column is a component of a Complex property? Should one do anything 
   different then? (i.e., If *Location* is an entity with a complex property named
   *Address*, then how does one get the column name for, say, *Address.Street*?)**

Answer (score 1):

***Here's a general-purpose algorithm for converting between conceptual and store information, written in Visual Basic 2010.***

I have written a new routine that to convert an entity/property pair into a table/column pair. This class, *MSLMappingAction*, takes in its constructor the model name and either an XElement XML tree, an MSL mapping file, or an XML string. One then uses the *ConceptualToStore* method to take String specifying entity and property "expressions" (stored in the *MSLConceptualInfo* structure) and find the table and column names (stored in the *MSLStoreInfo* structure).

**Notes:**

1. One could also write a "*StoreToConceptual*" method to convert in
   the other direction, but the XML queries would probably be a bit
   more complex. The same goes for handling
   navigation-propery/function/stored-procedure mappings.
2. *Beware inherited properties of derived entities!* If a property is
   not specific to the derived entity, then you should use the base
   entity's name.)

Here's the code.

**Host code:** (For the XML sample given [see bottom], it returns table name "Locations" and column name "Address_Street" for the store information when given the entity "Location" and the property expression "Address.Street" [and the conceptual model name "SCTModel"]):

```
Dim MSL As MSLMappingAction = New MSLMappingAction(".\SCTModel.msl", "SCTModel")

Dim ConceptualInfo As MSLConceptualInfo = New MSLConceptualInfo With {.EntityName = "Location", .PropertyName = "Address.Street"}
Dim StoreInfo As MSLStoreInfo = MSL.ConceptualToStore(ConceptualInfo)
MessageBox.Show(StoreInfo.TableName & ": " & StoreInfo.ColumnName)
```

**Class code:**

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Xml.Linq

''' <summary>
''' This class allows one to convert between an EF conceptual model's entity/property pair
''' and its database store's table/column pair.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>It takes into account entity splitting and complex-property designations;
''' it DOES NOT take into account inherited properties
''' (in such a case, you should access the entity's base class)</remarks>
Public Class MSLMappingAction

'   private fields and routines
Private mmaMSLMapping As XElement
Private mmaModelName, mmaNamespace As String

Private Function FullElementName(ByVal ElementName As String) As String
'   pre-pend Namespace to ElementName
Return "{" & mmaNamespace & "}" & ElementName
End Function

Private Sub ValidateParams(ByVal MappingXML As XElement, Byval ModelName As String)
'   verify that model name is specified
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ModelName) Then
    Throw New EntityException("Entity model name is not given!")
End If
'   verify that we're using C-S space
If MappingXML.@Space <> "C-S" Then
    Throw New MetadataException("XML is not C-S mapping data!")
End If
'   get Namespace and set private variables
mmaNamespace = MappingXML.@xmlns
mmaMSLMapping = MappingXML : mmaModelName = ModelName
End Sub

Private Function IsSequenceEmpty(Items As IEnumerable(Of XElement)) As Boolean
'   determine if query result is empty
Return _
    Items Is Nothing OrElse Items.Count = 0
End Function

'   properties
''' <summary>
''' Name of conceptual entity model
''' </summary>
''' <returns>Conceptual-model String</returns>
''' <remarks>Model name can only be set in constructor</remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property EntityModelName() As String
Get
    Return mmaModelName
End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Name of mapping namespace
''' </summary>
''' <returns>Namespace String of C-S mapping layer</returns>
''' <remarks>This value is determined when the XML mapping
''' is first parsed in the constructor</remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property MappingNamespace() As String
Get
    Return mmaNamespace
End Get
End Property

'   constructors
''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping information for an entity model (with XML tree)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="MappingXML">XML mapping tree</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New(ByVal MappingXML As XElement, ByVal ModelName As String)
ValidateParams(MappingXML, ModelName)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping information for an entity model (with XML file)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="MSLFile">MSL mapping file</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New(ByVal MSLFile As String, ByVal ModelName As String)
Dim MappingXML As XElement = XElement.Load(MSLFile)
ValidateParams(MappingXML, ModelName)
End Sub

'   methods
''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping infomration for an entity model (with XML String)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="XMLString">XML mapping String</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal XMLString As String, ByVal ModelName As String)
Return New MSLMappingAction(XElement.Parse(XMLString), ModelName)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Convert conceptual entity/property information into store table/column information
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ConceptualInfo">Conceptual-model data
''' (.EntityName = entity expression String, .PropertyName = property expression String)</param>
''' <returns>Store data (.TableName = table-name String, .ColumnName = column-name String)</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function ConceptualToStore(ByVal ConceptualInfo As MSLConceptualInfo) As MSLStoreInfo
Dim StoreInfo As New MSLStoreInfo
With ConceptualInfo
    '   prepare to query XML
    If Not .EntityName.Contains(".") Then
        '   make sure entity name is fully qualified
        .EntityName = mmaModelName & "." & .EntityName
    End If
    '   separate property names if there's complex-type nesting
    Dim Properties() As String = .PropertyName.Split(".")
    '   get relevant entity mapping
    Dim MappingInfo As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _                 
        (From mi In mmaMSLMapping.Descendants(FullElementName("EntityTypeMapping")) _
            Where mi.@TypeName = "IsTypeOf(" & .EntityName & ")" _
                OrElse mi.@TypeName = .EntityName _
         Select mi)
    '   make sure entity is in model
    If IsSequenceEmpty(MappingInfo) Then
        Throw New EntityException("Entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not found!")
    End If
    '   get mapping fragments
    Dim MappingFragments As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
        (From mf In MappingInfo.Descendants(FullElementName("MappingFragment")) _
         Select mf)
    '   make sure there's at least 1 fragment
    If IsSequenceEmpty(MappingFragments) Then
        Throw New EntityException("Entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not mapped!")
    End If
    '   search each mapping fragment for the desired property
    For Each MappingFragment In MappingFragments
        '   get physical table for this fragment
        StoreInfo.TableName = MappingFragment.@StoreEntitySet
        '   search property expression chain
        Dim PropertyMapping As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = {MappingFragment}
        '   parse complex property info (if any)
        For index = 0 To UBound(Properties) - 1
            '   go down 1 level
            Dim ComplexPropertyName = Properties(index)
            PropertyMapping = _
                (From pm In PropertyMapping.Elements(FullElementName("ComplexProperty")) _
                    Where pm.@Name = ComplexPropertyName)
            '   verify that the property specified for this level exists
            If IsSequenceEmpty(PropertyMapping) Then
                Exit For 'go to next fragment if not
            End If
        Next index
        '   property not found? try next fragment
        If IsSequenceEmpty(PropertyMapping) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        '   parse scalar property info
        Dim ScalarPropertyName = Properties(UBound(Properties))
        Dim ColumnName As String = _
            (From pm In PropertyMapping.Elements(FullElementName("ScalarProperty")) _
                Where pm.@Name = ScalarPropertyName _
                Select CN = pm.@ColumnName).FirstOrDefault
        '   verify that scalar property exists
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColumnName) Then
            '   yes? return (exit) with column info
            StoreInfo.ColumnName = ColumnName : Return StoreInfo
        End If
    Next MappingFragment
    '   property wasn't found
    Throw New EntityException("Property """ & .PropertyName _
        & """ of entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not found!")
End With
End Function
End Class

''' <summary>
''' Conceptual-model entity and property information  
''' </summary>
Public Structure MSLConceptualInfo
''' <summary>
''' Name of entity in conceptual model
''' </summary>
''' <value>Entity expression String</value>
''' <remarks>EntityName may or may not be fully qualified (i.e., "ModelName.EntityName");
''' when a mapping method is called by the MSLMappingAction class, the conceptual model's
''' name and a period will be pre-pended if it's omitted</remarks>
Public Property EntityName As String
''' <summary>
''' Name of property in entity
''' </summary>
''' <value>Property expression String</value>
''' <remarks>PropertyName may be either a stand-alone scalar property or a scalar property
''' within 1 or more levels of complex-type properties; in the latter case, it MUST be fully
''' qualified (i.e., "ComplexPropertyName.InnerComplexPropertyName.ScalarPropertyName")</remarks>
Public Property PropertyName As String
End Structure

''' <summary>
''' Database-store table and column information
''' </summary>
Public Structure MSLStoreInfo
''' <summary>
''' Name of table in database
''' </summary>
Public Property TableName As String
''' <summary>
''' Name of column in database table
''' </summary>
Public Property ColumnName As String
End Structure
```

The catch is that the node names all have to have a namespace prepended to them. It tripped me up until I checked my elements 1 at a time!

Here's the *sample* XML -- which I load from the ".\SCTModel.msl" file in the code above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
  <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="SCTModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="SocialContactsTracker">
    <EntitySetMapping Name="SocialContacts">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.SocialContact)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateAdded" ColumnName="DateAdded" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Information" ColumnName="Information" />
          <ComplexProperty Name="DefaultAssociations" TypeName="SCTModel.DefaultAssociations">
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultLocationID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultLocationID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultEmailID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultEmailID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultPhoneNumberID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultPhoneNumberID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultWebsiteID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultWebsiteID" />
          </ComplexProperty>
          <ScalarProperty Name="Picture" ColumnName="Picture" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Person)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts_Person">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateOfBirth" ColumnName="DateOfBirth" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="FirstName" ColumnName="FirstName" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="LastName" ColumnName="LastName" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Organization)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts_Organization">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateOfCreation" ColumnName="DateOfCreation" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Locations">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Location)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Locations">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="City" ColumnName="City" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="State" ColumnName="State" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="ZIP" ColumnName="ZIP" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Country" ColumnName="Country" />
          <ComplexProperty Name="Address" TypeName="SCTModel.Address">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Street" ColumnName="Address_Street" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Apartment" ColumnName="Address_Apartment" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="HouseNumber" ColumnName="Address_HouseNumber" />
          </ComplexProperty>
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="PhoneNumbers">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.PhoneNumber)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="PhoneNumbers">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Number" ColumnName="Number" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="PhoneType" ColumnName="PhoneType" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Emails">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Email)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Emails">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DomainName" ColumnName="DomainName" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="UserName" ColumnName="UserName" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Websites">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Website)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Websites">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="URL" ColumnName="URL" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactWebsite" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactWebsite" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactWebsite">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Website">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Websites_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactPhoneNumber" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactPhoneNumber" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactPhoneNumber">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="PhoneNumber">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="PhoneNumbers_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactEmail" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactEmail" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactEmail">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Email">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Emails_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactLocation" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactLocation" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactLocation">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Location">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Locations_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
  </EntityContainerMapping>
</Mapping>
```